# What parties are obliged to make "reasonable adjustments"?

Tags: united-kingdom, disabilities

There is a legal phrase reasonable adjustment that refers to various parties duty to adjust their interaction with disabled people for the latter's ease and practicality. What types of parties are subject to this duty, in what contexts, and what laws does this duty and related phrases stem from?

Is it only the equality act 2010 (which covers discrimination against various different characteristics even though this phrase would seem to refer only to sceneries involving disabled individuals), or are there other pieces of legislation that also refer to this concept? Perhaps legislation and deals specifically with issues of disabilities?

For that matter, can the idea be applied in relation to other protected characteristics that disabilities?

as far as the equality act goes, there appear to be a great many sections which make reference to this, but it seems that many of them in turn are clarifications or elaborations to aid in applying it correctly to various specific settings. Is there any "root" use that sets out where and when such adjustments are required and where/when they are not?

Comment: The more usual phrase in E&W is "reasonable adjustments" and the legislation is the [Equality Act 2010](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/contents), but the scope of the question is far too broad to answer, in my opinion, without copy-pasting rafts of its provisions. Maybe if the OP concentrated on one particular set of circumstances a focused answer could be achievable.

Comment: Perhaps an answer could more extensively explain why that is the case at a broad/high level.